# symfony constuctor error no such service exist

Tags: symfony

I am new with symfony i am trying to use the constructor but it doesn't work and i don't understand why

```
error:
Cannot autowire service \App\Controller\OutputController argument $product of method &__construct() references class App\Entity\Product but no such service exists.



<?php

    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Entity\Product;

    class OutputController  {

        private $product;
        public function __construct(Product $product)    
        {
            $this->product = $product;
        }

        public function jsonFormat() {                     
            return json_encode($this->product->toArray());
        }

    }
?>
```

thanks

Comment: You have to specify the symfony version (at least). Please read the [Asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to formulate a better, useful and on-topic questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use autowiring and you try to autowire a entity. By default they are **not** exposed as services by this config line from the default `app/config/services.yml`:

```
App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

As you can see, symfony exposes all files from `src/*` except from:

> Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php

---

**You should not expose entities as services and you should not rely on entities in your controller**, [Use services for that](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)